# Bezier curves hair makes blender slow

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I have made this hair with bezier curves following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/QocAk6TNKp4 . Now I'm going to rig the character, but I'm afraid it's going to be slow, since in editing mode the hair lags. Any advice?[image]

Comment: There really is no reason for it to be slow if you followed the tutorial. If you do not have tons of curves with loads of vertexes and the curve you are sweeping along them is not extremely complex. Provide us with more information. What is your HW setup? How many polygons does the hair have? What is the resolution of curves? How many polygons are there in the whole scene? Nobody can help you with the information you provided

Comment: If you have lag in the viewport you can hide or replace it. Use the [Outliner Restriction Toggles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141145/107598) to hide the hair with the "eye" icon in the viewport or even disable it with the "monitor" icon in the viewport to save memory while you do the animation. If you want to see it you can use a low-poly object in the viewport instead, while for rendering the real hair object is used ("camera" icon).