# When trying to render my objects will not turn out in the render view

Tags: rendering

I have tried the Ctrl+Alt+H shortcut [image]and in the first picture everything is supposed to render. Any help is appreciated and if there is any need for clarification I will answer as soon as possible.

Here is the render view for reference
[image]

Comment: This question gets asked quite often and has possibly been answered before. Please **read carefully** through the answers on these pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632) and [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490). Try the proposed solutions. If you still can't solve your problem, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information

Comment: I figured it out though the solution wasn't in that link. I was using the wrong renderer Blender Render when I should have been using Cycles Render.