# render view not working in camera view/blank render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I can't see my project in the rendered view (ctrl+z) when im in camera view but it works when I exit camera view. This is what it looks like before and after I press CTRL+Z [image: here is camera view before I ctrl+z]

[image: here it is after I press ctrl+z]

and when I render my animation all I get is a blank black image. It was working before but I think I might have accidentally pressed something that made it this way and have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Please **read carefully** through the answers on these pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632) and [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490). Try the proposed solutions. If you still can't solve your problem, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: I figured it out I pressed shift+B in camera view and accidentally selected a really tiny area..... yeah im dumb.