# Scene is rendering black only

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I've researched many posts on this topic and have gone down the entire checklist, but I can't figure out why my scene is rendering completely black (Blender Render).

1. I've added lighting, and have selected appropriate light colors
2. Camera is pointing in right direction, and settings are good
3. I restarted computer, so no RAM issue
4. Nodes look correct, etc
5. etc, etc.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've uploaded on blend-exchange here: ([image]). Tks!

[image]

Comment: This question gets asked quite often. Please use the search box at the top. Also look through the many causes of blank rendering here: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490) and here: [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632)

Comment: Many thanks, @cegaton. I spent around 3-4 hours looking at all the posts on this subject, and possible causes, but none seem to apply in my case. I checked all the possible causes in the links you provided, but nothing works. I'm going nuts here!

Comment: Strangely, I added a World data-block, and then suddenly the scene renders fine now . . . Should that change have made the difference? And if so, why

Comment: Now I added a plane underneath my cube object, and I can't see the cube anymore (or the plane). All I can see is the "Sky" the World. I'm very confused!

Comment: Deleted World, and then re-added a new World, and now I can render everything again . . .