# When I rendered my project, it seems to be completely grey. Also, I have Blender v2.79

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a noob at Blender so that maybe the problem. I have Blender version 2.79. I rendered it a couple of times, but it still came out gray. These are screenshots taken before and after the render. (the first one is before, the second one is after)

[image]

[image]

Please help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from Blender Render to Cycles Render in the drop down menu along the top? That's where I'd start at least.