# For some reason a chair i downloaded for my scene doesnt show in the final render i dont know how to get it in the render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, visibility

I have made an bedroom it looks fine in the viewport render but when I actually render it the chairs doesn't show.

I got the object from Blenderkit but I also got some other stuff that shows like the katana

Viewport:
[image]

Render:
[image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Comment: Please share the whole screen including your outliner window to see the visibility settings for your objects.