# When rendering an image the output is grey

Tags: rendering, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I've tried rendering an image using the Cycles render engine. here is the output:(everything looks good)
[image]

I tried rendering the same image, but using Radeon ProRender engine. This is how it looks at samples 28/128(not ready yet, it looks fine):

[image]

And this is the output.. I don't understand why I get a grey image. Did I miss something ?
[image]

EDIT
Here are my blender preferences
[image]

 I have also installed this from their official website //// i do not know what other settings so show here
[image]

 My .blend file is this [image]

Comment: Hi. I would say, if you are watching a tutorial just re-watch it and re-do it until you get it. It might be a couple of times, but that's the whole point of it being a recorded tutorial. If you are struggling, it means you are learning something new.

Comment: I also gave this question a downvote, that is not related to the simplicity of it, it is because you have not provided any information needed to answer the question. I would suggest to edit the question and describe in detail what you did also provide screenshots including your render settings and outliner and a .blend file if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: I edited the question with the render settings (I hope that's hat you meant)

Comment: Duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) Output node disconnected and [Why does my object not show u-up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) Reason #2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Render Layer is not connected to the composite node.

You need to go to Compositing, here you need to connect the render layer image to the composite node

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! this was what was not working for me, thanks again! much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In your Compositing tab, the Render Layers node is not connected to the Composite node.
There used to be a Denoise node in between them, but I think that got disconnected when you switched to the AMD Radeon Pro Renderer.
I think you should directly connect the Render Layers node to the Composite node, because the Denoise node only works for Cycles (someone correct me if I'm wrong):

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I must have overlooked the other answer above that's the same as mine.

Comment: thank you too for clarifications!