# Eeevee and Cycles animation/image are only rendered gray

Tags: rendering

I have rendered the animation in eevee and cycles but the rendered video (output) is only a gray background please help soon it works fine in workplace render this:[image]

EDIT: A workaround? if i copy all my objects to an another file (created new blender file) then rendered it works but that still does not tell me why this is happening.

my prefences: [image]

file here for your ref:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NUUK_sybn7VVQ2-wfU0V8vS7tcxV9U2/view?usp=drivesdk [file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NUUK_sybn7VVQ2-wfU0V8vS7tcxV9U2/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: How to include file?

Comment: Show us your background setup

Comment: how to i am new

Comment: please share your file (remove all the useless objects and pack the images): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When rendering an image the output is grey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200828/when-rendering-an-image-the-output-is-grey)

Comment: I don't know where to get to that screen

Comment: I have Tried that Emir but that is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection containing your models is disabled for rendering:

[image: collection rendering disabled]

Hence, all objects contained inside, including your bird and the green cube, were just not being rendered, leading to only your scene world's gray color to be visible.

Enable the collection's rendering and it will work normally.

---

Unrelated note: if you put a green cube behind your bird in order to key out the green for transparency in a later use, that's unnecessary.
Enable transparency in Properties Editor → Render tab → Film panel. Then in your file output, make sure you use a file format that supports RGBA colors like EXR or TGA.

Comment: I did not see that wow I was so stupid thank you

Answer (score -1):

In the *Output Properties* tab, there is a dropdown called *Post Processing*.

Enabling the *Compositor* checkbox might solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have checked that thank you for telling the comment above was the answer but still
thank you very much and have a great day