# Scene not visible in render

Tags: rendering, animation, camera, eevee-render-engine, scene

I'm using blender 2.90.1 version Eevee Render Engine. My previous Scenes are no problem. it's rendered. but this file is not rendering. What is this problem?

I use particle system, soft body in this scene.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello. A gif about the rendering that is not rendering is useless... could you show your setting, in particular the outliner part with objects supposed to be rendered (and scenes settings if several). Not a gif, something readable...

Comment: Please give me a minute.

Comment: I imagine the file is too large to be uploaded... so... question(s): is the layer enabled for rendering?

Comment: Yes it's no Problem. I rendered 5 Scenes in last 5 Days. it's not Problem. but this file is not rendering. I don't change any of these blender files render settings. all of these file are same render setting I use. But this file is not Rendering. I can't understand.

Comment: No issue or error message in the console ?

Comment: Ok, Friend. I found it. it is my Wrong. I use reference videos for creating animation in video sequencer editor. Because of those videos rendered in render time. I delete this videos and it's fine. Thanks friend for reply me. thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) **Reason #4**

Comment: This is entirely my fault. This is not a problem with the Blender software.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. it is my Wrong. I use reference videos for creating animation in video sequencer editor. Because of those videos rendered in render time. I delete this videos and it's fine.

[image]