# render animation gives blank window

Tags: rendering, animation

I clicked on render animation (F12) and nothing appears.
Here a image of the result:
[image]

Comment: Possibly something is missing in your compositing tab.

Comment: It is hard to help you with the exisisting information on the post. Read trhough the many reasons why a render can be blank here: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) and [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)