# Blender 2.91 - Half of my objects are not appearing on render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, resolution

I've been setting up my scene and tried to render to check how the noise looks on the sunbed. Render looks like a total disaster - resolution on moon surface is way worse than it should be (displace is set to 7 on render and 5 on viewport), my glowing guy and the sunbed just vanished.

Have no idea what's going on, all objects are checked to appear on render.

pics:

[image]
[image]
rendered in cycles

EDIT: I checked every possible cause in the answer and it didn't change the result. My question is about not rendering certain objects and rendering lower resolution moon surface than in viewport even though it's set to higher.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Comment: Seems like the surface of the moon is inflated in the render. I suspect it might be covering the other objects. There is probably something wrong with displacement. If you shared the file, it would be a matter of seconds for pretty much anyone here to determine the problem and provide you with a solution. You did not share the file however.