# Rendered image is only a transparent screen

Tags: rendering

I was doing a roblox gfx, but when I rendered it, all I was seeing was a transparent screen, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please read through the many causes of blank screens in the following links:  [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) and [Why does my object not show up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: ok thank you so much i hope this works <3