# Camera Clipped View

Tags: rendering, camera

I cannot figure out why the camera displays and renders a portion of the image, but not entirely.

[image]

I am attaching an image image of what the camera is actually displaying, and will try to figure out how to attach a 2nd image of the scene I am trying to accomplish

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) See situation number 11.

Answer (score 4):

Try to turn up the clipping distance on your camera. You do this by selecting your camera, then goinh to it's menu over on the very right and turning up the Clip end.
[image]