# Only one object showing up in blender while rendering

Tags: rendering

Guys im really panicking...
So im making a GFX and im using blender 2.79, but when i start rendering, only one object show up and the background is transparent.
When i press the render preview, it shows all of the objects.
[image: this is my screen when rendering]

[image: this is my screen when im using the preview]

Comment: Did you somehow accidentally set most of your objects to be hidden in render?

Comment: Consider sharing a screenshot of your outliner and how did you set up your compositing. Ideally share a minified version of your file showing the issue: https://blend-exchange.com/ Also, please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank