# Grey render result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, camera, animation-nodes

new to blender and I can't figure out why is it. I attach the link of the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dXX1Yx2eBiQcZbqe8wXSoKhHJdYOjbH0/view?usp=sharing I can't tell if its the camera or  the material nodes or something else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) (No. 9)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your image is disconnected from the outputs in the compositor:

[image: Comp]