# Animation render screen is black for the first few seconds

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

Half of the screen is black in the render for the first 3 seconds.
 
[image: Screenshot of the animation] 
Here is the [link for the animation, its only 4mb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tMug53qkp1Gorh2hI0kIfhsnZVE6IIxU/view?usp=sharing).

Here is the [link to the blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvTbnRjj0DyipoosZmmxXnNYH8JfM87S/view?usp=sharing) . **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number 6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's caused by the object called *Plane*, your camera is at the middle of it:

[image]

Comment: Yes I added it just for reference and thanks a lot !!!