# Camera stuck in a resolution

Tags: rendering, animation, camera, 2d, resolution

When I try to increase or decrease the FOV/resolution of my camera view, it can't get more large vertically or horizontally, and when I try to render it, it's just plain black, and this is a problem since I want to increase the size of the project so that it's not all blurry when rendering with the original size (256x256).[image]

Comment: Make sure your camera rotation is correct and Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: You should focus on one problem per question. I guess your size problem and the black screen might have different causes. My answer is for what I guess your size problem is.

Comment: your sizing issue is likely because your X resolution is very small, if you increase it the aspect ratio will change, could you post a screenshot of your camera settings? For the problem with black screen it could be because there is no lighting, could you post a screen shot of both the world view as well as the shader for the backdrop?

Comment: Peterdagrape.
When I try to resize the image it tries to get resized in, let's say, 360 pixels in  X dimension but all it does is get thinner and thinner in one direction, and when I try to render it just renders black, it just simply renders all frames in 1 second and just won't render anything, just black, hope this anwers your question.

Comment: Gordon Brinkman.
Your third statement is the problem, does this help?

Comment: Then maybe the fourth statement is the solution...?

Comment: It is probably the problem, sorry for the inconveniences, im just really dumb with all of this explaining thing.

Comment: Oh wow, it actually helped, thanks man!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No solution here for the black render, hard to tell from the screenshot which settings might be wrong. But about the size:

Your screenshot doesn't really show what the problem is... you have set a resolution of 256 × 516 pixels and the camera looks like the aspect ratio fits these dimensions.

So if you're saying "it can't get more large", do you mean the camera's field of view doesn't get larger so that it extends the objects vertically or horizontically?

The FOV is dependent on the camera settings, especially the *Focal Length*. How much you can see through the camera is determined by the focal length and the distance to the objects - more or less like in real life.

For example if you want to render a typical 16:9 image, it doesn't matter if you set it to 1920 × 1080 pixels, 3840 × 2160 pixels or 256 × 144 pixels, the camera's view will always be the same. Just the rendered image changes in size. The same goes for setting a resolution and then change the percentage into something different than 100%.

Comment: Downvoting because I have to guess a solution for lack of clarification in the question is quite impolite.

Comment: Well I edited the question, hope that helps.