# Why does appear a green light while rendering

Tags: modeling

Sorry I'm new to blender i don't know why it does this
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: Number 2 in your case https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53633/2214 ... just in opposite way :) Or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67491/2214 number 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another light that is hiddent in preview but active in final render:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and i'm sorry fot this stupid error