# Render issues – Geometrical Pattern

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

I checked the similar question and didn't see anything like what IM experiencing.

I'm rendering with Eevee, a render sample of 100.
When I send it to render, I get a very light grey screen with a slightly darker geometric pattern on it.
I don't know how else to explain.

I have tried a few youtube vids on Eevee rendering, and I am stuck.
Any advice is welcomed.

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to post screenshots or include a link to your .blend file? (https://pasteall.org/blend/) It's hard to identify an issue without being able to properly look at this.

Comment: You can post a screengrab. Just edit your question and drag and drop your image into the editor or click the image icon in the body header and follow the prompts. To take a screen grab in Blender, use Blender's Window > Screenshot menu.

Comment: screen grab posted, thank gents

Comment: Please send over your .blend file.

Comment: Thanks @Blendmaster how do i send file

Comment: My blend file is too big for pasteall.org

Comment: Interesting one :) https://imgur.com/lJhyKsJ ... you can try to delete object per object and see if issue still persist :) Like that, you can get also been file lighter to share :)

Comment: how about using google drive, dropbox, or blendexchange?

Comment: you are genius@vklidu

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/169hsEYpRlRRixMJLu-qW7sWWpsrjM8TK?usp=sharing

Comment: change sharing option, like now people have to ask you for permission.

Comment: Yeah, I can't access it.

Comment: sorry, here is shared link, I do appreciate.... https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/169hsEYpRlRRixMJLu-qW7sWWpsrjM8TK?usp=sharing

Comment: Can be marked as duplicate of [11. Clip Start](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633) ... or [12. Object blocks View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67491#67491)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is object *Cylinder.001* hidden from Viewport, but still enabled for Rendering ... check Outliner Editor.

This object is blocking Camera view. If *Cylinder.001* should be a part of your render you would have to move Camera a bit forward or enlarge *Cylinder.001*

... or go to *Properties Editor > Camera Properties > Lens >* **Clip Start** and change value from 0.1 at least 0.4

---

BTW as recommended in my comment, you could discover the issue by your self if you would delete objects / collections in a few steps to see what affects render issue.

Comment: you are right, sorry over tired and over frazzeled meant I was thinking logically. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your background texture is messed up. If you look in the render preview, the hdri doesn't show. I reimported all your assets into a fresh new EEVEE scene, added an hdri, and the render looks completely fine. Try doing the same. Hope this helps!

Comment: So I need to add an hdri in the world shader editor and not just choose from the drop-down menu?

Comment: I'd copy all assets to a new file, then choose a new HDRi. Also, If you are using an HDRI, keep in mind it won't look too realistic (unlike cycles.)

Comment: A big thanks to all who commented