# Black marks appearing in my apple near the stem

Tags: rendering, mesh

[image]Why are those black marks appearing in my apple near the stem, which is not shown in the YouTube tutorial video?

Upload File Link--> https://blend-exchange.com/b/Yr3ymrol [enter link description here](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VnWwj44w)

[image]

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Comment: Apart from giving some suggestions and modifying my question can somebody give a solution to the query which is actually i came here for, please

Comment: what black marks are you referring to? Could you please highlight in your picture?

Comment: @moonboots Please check the picture above

and also can u please give the reason why render is showing black even after adding light and camera

Comment: Only activate the collection with your apple, in the Viewport Shading activate the 2 Lighting options, create a camera, create a light, and you'll be able to render. As for the dark artefacts, you have overlapping vertices, select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Answer (score 1):

For the dark artefacts, you have overlapping vertices, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*:

[image]

For the render, make sure before the render that only the collection with your object is activated:

[image]

In the *Viewport Shading* panel activate the scene lights and world, otherwise they won't be taken into account for render:

[image]

Create a camera, create a light, render:

[image]

Comment: For dark artifacts it worked but for render it still showing silhouettes with no light even after adding camera and light exactly above the object and turn on of scene lights & world

Comment: could you please share the latest version of your file?

Comment: I have updated the link above with new file please check

Comment: Swtich to Rendered preview to see what it gives, as you see your light strength is much too low, increase it up

Comment: Yes, Increasing the power of the light worked sorry for being ignorant. thumbs up

Comment: @ESF This site is not a regular forum, Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).