# Why won’t my 3d model render even though it’s visible in the 3d viewport?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

this is my first time trying to make anything in blender and I followed a tutorial on youtube (to make 3d inflatable text) that went great right up until I pressed f12 to get the final render. The final render shows a flat screen with a gradient of color from one of my light sources to a different light source while my 3d model text is nowhere to be seen (the 3d viewport shows the light sources shining onto my 3d modeled text) I’ve checked around for other people with the same issue and i can’t find any other people with the same issue or a solution that solves the problem.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank