# problems with Cycles, totally empty image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I was trying to render an architectural model with Cycles, but the render appears empty.

Comment: hello, maybe give more details, or even share your file (only keep several objects to make it lighter)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to look for in such cases:

- Disconnected compositor Composite node
- Sequencer activated and not empty
- View layer disabled for rendering
- All objects or collections disabled for rendering