# Black render on Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATED QUESTION

As mentioned, I have tried everything under [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) and nothings has worked.

I'm using blender 3.0.1 to render a scene. It renders properly with both Eevee and workbench but cycles in specific (both supported and experimental) cause all rendered frames to turn out black.
It's not a problem with the scene as even in cycles it renders the objects correctly and only then turns the entire frame black at the end, regardless of output format.

I have tried every workaround I could find. No problems with the scene. Sequencer and dithering are off under post processing. All exposures are set to 1.

Is there anything else I could try or is it broken in this version?

Comment: Access to a file is going to be necessary to investigate, I think.

Comment: if you want your question reopened you need to provide a simplified blend file reproducing the problem (meaning remove evevrything in the file except the parts that cause black result) else it will remain closed.

Comment: As suggested, please provide a minimal failing file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . Then  we can reopen, and  test for solutions not appearing in the supposed duplicate.