# Why is my Blender render blank?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've tried everything I understood from this question, [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank), but pressing F12 still gives me a blank render window.

File is here: [image]

Update: I just noticed there is what looks like a little error message briefly in the status bar: "Build without OpenImageDenoiser"

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Scene renders just fine for me, so i guess its not a scene setting, but more likely a technical problem on your side. Do other blend files render? Does it render if you change something under _File > Preferences... > Cycles Render Devices_?

Comment: Your file renders perfectly fine on my PC. Maybe it's an issue with your graphics card and/or the necessary drivers?

Comment: Thank you both. That's so weird. I don't know what else to check. I'll try update all my drivers and install the CUDA thing I guess.

Comment: Ok, the problem is the Blender version in APT on Linux is old and broken. Installing Blender with Snap so it's as recent as possible fixed it.