# StoryPencil Scene is Blank

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I seem to be messing up Storypencil somehow. Why does the scene I edited not show anything back in VSE. The scene strip is blank?

If I use *Edit* and go back to the scene its all there, the Grease pencil drawings, its Key frames and layers.

More details of what I was doing at the time. I added 2 scenes each with only the first frame drawn on then the 3rd Scene was going to cover the next 6 panels of my story board because they use the same background, so I drew them on 6 frames in the same scene with the back ground on its own layer.

Looks/Plays/Works fine in the scene but back in the VSE window only the first 2 scenes play the new/3rd scene plays-Blank. Do I need to link or update something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/297769#297769) In my answer there I explain that you cannot put your scene in the sequencer in the same scene, you need an extra scene for that.