# Why I can't output anything with cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I can't out put anything with cycles?
[image: Main layout]

this is my main layout ↑

and when I press the Render Animation button, I can see nothing, and no files were output:
[image]

I have even tried to output in two different computers but all failed.
I can't render with GPU and CPU, they both failed.

these are my settings, all my settings are the same as the video:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please tell me if you need more information, and thanks for your kind help!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Comment: In your screenshot of the render window it says "Synchronizing object", so it hasn't even really started rendering that frame, it is still in the preparations for rendering. Maybe you could show a screenshot where it is actually rendering the frame?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a mis-spelled folder name in the output path ("1-VideoStoriage" instead of "1-VideoStorage")? Each frame will take almost 6 minutes to render according to the header so maybe you aren't waiting long enough?

Comment: Oh I found the real answer is that I didn't waited long enough, it takes 6 minutes to render 1 frame, this question is solved, but I'll going to find why it takes so long, I don't think RTX 3060Ti will cost so much time...

Comment: @JiuyeAyan You can answer your own question so I suggest you post that comment as an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I found the real answer is that I didn't waited long enough, it takes 6 minutes to render 1 frame, this question is solved.
Thanks for the help from John Eason, Gordon Brinkmann andd Duarte Farrajota Ramos.

I didn't notice that there were infromations on the render window.

[image]

and I also solved the problem of the long render time, thanks for the help from Blunder:

[image]

Thanks for the help from all of you!