# Some images from the animation not rendering at all

Tags: rendering, animation, error

So I did kinda mess up at the start; applied a texture to a plane and rendered it before it had applied fully and as it turns out, it got applied when the 57th frame was rendering, so I got all frames rendered, with the first 56 frames being rendered without the texture.

I deleted the incomplete frames and tried to render the first 56 afterwards, and they just showed up blank; setting up a new camera or putting the renders in a new folder doesn't help either. The problem only lies in the texture being applied WHILE it was rendering as the frame at which the texture had already applied before being rendered was frame 57, which got easily rendered.

Here's frame 48 - https://imgur.com/a/mntjmFE, and its render - https://imgur.com/a/voTzE9T

Here's frame 57 - https://imgur.com/a/mX1B6Wa, and it's render - https://imgur.com/a/x2a0Hql

The renders just come out blank, and even in the files, they don't open at all..

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i tried doing that but it says i've surpasses the limit of image size, and compressing it doesn't help either..

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for the link; i'll try them out and check

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos one of the listed solutions worked! thanks for that!