# It's not showing up in animation render-- it's all blank

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, render-layers, render-passes

I have all this animation and audio, so when I render the animation, it does not show up, completely blank. Does anyone know how to fix this error?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render result is completely blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank). The thing is, if you want to combine footage with your scene, the answer below with disabling the sequencer or removing the strips will not help you. Therefore you need a _Scene_ strip in your sequencer, but that is a bit tricky as I explained more in detail in my answer at the linked duplicate question. Or you just render your scene without sound and video background like suggested in the answer by @moonboots below, then later combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have video strips in the Video Sequencer it will try to render it instead of the 3D scene, so you need to either remove these strips or disable the *Post Processing > Sequencer* option:

[image]