# Render goes black

Tags: rendering

I just started Blender and I have made my model, environment and objects but when I try rendering it, it all turns black. I have searched this problem on this website but none of the answers seemed to help.

**Solutions that haven't worked**

- Turning on Environment lighting
- Making the image Local

I have tried accessing the compositor and Use nodes but, it comes up with no nodes. It comes up with nothing.

Please help!

Comment: Without more information is hard to tell what's wrong. A few possible reasons:
  - There are no lights in scene
 - [Objects disabled for Render in Outliner (camera icon)](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/one-object-wont-show-up-in-final-render-even-though-it-shows-up-in-the-preview/27722#27722)
 - [Strips in VSE and Sequencer box enabled in Post-Processing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51179/blank-image-when-i-render/51181#51181) - [Objects in different layer or not part of the render Layers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35020/1853)

Comment: - Camera view blocked by other objects

 - Active camera set incorrectly or aiming in a different direction

 - [An object in the scene has been set as camera](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46487/i-accidentally-set-an-object-as-camera-how-do-i-undo-this)

 - Output node in compositor disconnected

 - [Film exposure is set to 0 (Cycles)](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51951/my-render-is-turning-out-black/51957#51957)

 - [The scene is so out of focus that there is no recognizable image](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55410/1853)

Comment: It would be best to upload your blend file or a way to reproduce the issue, it could be a wide range of options.

Comment: Check this post as well: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53633/1853