# Objects missing in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, scene, world

whenever I try to render an image all the props/rigs and sky appear in the final render but the actual scene/environment does not.
this is what I'm trying to render:
[image]

this is what is rendering:
[image]

please help this is for a final year multimedia major project!!!

Comment: In the menu on the top right corner, select the object that wont apear in the render. Make sure that the little camera on the far right of selected box isn't grayed out

Comment: related:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/one-object-wont-show-up-in-final-render-even-though-it-shows-up-in-the-preview

Comment: One other GOTCHA is an animation frame you aren't aware of that is moving an object out of camera. This is routine with purchased objects that you Append into your drawing. Make sure to check your Timeline for keyframes for the offending object.

Answer (score 1):

@cegaton select the affected objects and be sure the icon camera in the outliner window is active.

[image: Restrict rendering]

Or be sure the object properties "Cycle Settings" has the Camera selected in the Ray visibility settings.

[image]